# How do you read data from mySQL using node.js and post back to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am trying to read data from `MySQL` and then if a name matches, post back the data back on the same page. I don't seem to get the result back on the page? What is wrong?

I am learning to use `NodeJS` and it works on console, but trying to do on HTML

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "petra",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydatabase"
});

function readmySQL() { // function readmySQL is triggered from a html page on click
  var getname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Select all customers and return the result object:
  con.query("SELECT name, address, contact FROM myaddress", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log(result);
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      var row = result[key];
      if (getname == row.name){ // match entered name to datatbase user name
        document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = "Hello you have entered " + getname;
      }
      console.log(row.name + " , " + row.address + " , " + row.contact);
    });

    connection.end();
  }); 
});
}
```

Comment: You can follow this boilerplate express js with MySQL and html integration  https://github.com/chutiphon-k/express-mysql-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS runs on the server. Script inside HTML files runs on the client. You don't include server code on the client. Instead, you send messages to the server code from the client, and interpret the results. So the standard way to do this is to define a resource on the server that generates the content or data you want to generate, and to retrieve that content or data from the client, using just normal page loading or "ajax".

so you have to create http server by node js ( Check express js ) 
implement your web services in the server and call it from front end by ajax